# How to compose using the _Cons prism

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm trying to implement a fairly simple piece of code using lenses. However, I've hit a point where I want to be able to add and remove from a list. I've simplified it down to the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, FlexibleContexts, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module LensExample where

import qualified Control.Lens.TH as LensTH
import Control.Lens.Cons (_Cons)
import qualified Control.Lens.Fold

data StackExample = StackExample {
    _internal :: [String]
} deriving (Show)

start = StackExample { _internal = ["Hello", "World"]}

LensTH.makeLenses 'StackExample

popString :: [String] -> Maybe (String, [String])
popString ss = Control.Lens.Fold.preview _Cons ss

popWithPrism :: StackExample -> Maybe (String, StackExample)
popWithPrism s = Control.Lens.Fold.preview _xxx s
```

How I combine `internal` and `_Cons` to produce `_xxx`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be:

```
popWithPrism :: StackExample -> Maybe (String, StackExample)
popWithPrism = preview $ internal . _Cons . alongside id (re internal)
```

The idea is to target the inner list, split it with `_Cons`, and map each part of the resulting tuple with [`alongside`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:alongside)—in particular the second element, in order to re-apply the `StackExample` constructor.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, it definitely works, but is there a way to modify the expression so that it works with `review` as well as `preview`?

Comment: @JulianBirch Using `bimapping` instead of `alongside` and `Control.Lens.from` instead of `re` seems to do the trick: `internal . _Cons . bimapping id (Control.Lens.from internal) :: Prism' StackExample (String,StackExample)`. Unlike `alongside`, `bimapping` can return an isomorphism from two other isos, and this allows us to preserve the "prismaticness" of `_Cons`.

Comment: Is it possible to have an expression that satisfies both? (I'm not sure I've got the background to understand why not.)

Comment: @JulianBirch The expression with `bimapping` is a valid `Prism`, so you can use it with both `preview` and `review` just fine. The idea is that a  `Prism` might match or not, but when it matches, it must not lose information about the original value, otherwise that value can't be reconstructed when going in the opposite direction. When we compose `_Cons` with a mere lens, the lens might focus on some part of the result and discard the rest. But when we compose with an `Iso`, we preserve all information, so we still end up with a valid `Prism`.

Comment: I've been tinkering, trying to extend this trick to record types with more than one field, here: https://gist.github.com/danidiaz/ff76231a4d666415c10e7504784ff128